# ¿Cómo adaptar un query complejo al ORM de Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estoy intentando adaptar un query a rails, dentro del query hay un subquery con un "From" haciendo llamado a otro modelo,cosa que no se de que forma hacerlo. El query original es este:

```
SELECT B.Codigo, C.NombreCorto, B.Descripcion, B.HI, B.latitude, B.longitude, C.Direccion, ISNULL((SELECT SUM(TOTAL) 
FROM Venta 
WHERE RutaId=B.RutaId AND DiaO=B.DiaO AND CodCliente=B.Codigo AND Cancelada='0' AND TOTAL>0),0) AS TOTAL 
FROM BitacoraTiempos B LEFT JOIN Clientes C ON C.IdCli=B.Codigo 
WHERE B.RutaId='161' AND B.DiaO='893' 
ORDER by B.HI
```

y esto es lo que he realizado hasta ahora:

```
 def self.search_gps_venta(params)

    query = select('[bitacoratiempos].Codigo,[bitacoratiempos].RutaId,[bitacoratiempos].Descripcion,[bitacoratiempos].HI,[bitacoratiempos].latitude,[clientes].NombreCorto AS c_nombre,[clientes].Direccion AS c_direccion')
         .joins('left join clientes ON bitacoratiempos.Codigo=clientes.IdCli')
         .where("(bitacoratiempos.RutaId = :rutaId or :rutaId = '') AND (bitacoratiempos.DiaO = :diaO or :diaO = '') AND (bitacoratiempos.IdEmpresa = :idempresa)",{rutaId: params[:search], diaO: params[:diaO]})
    query

  end
```

En el controlador lo llamo de la siguiente forma:

```
  def busqueda_gps_venta
    @ventas = Bitacoratiempo.search_gps_venta(params)

    respond_to do |format|
    format.js
    end
  end
```

Como puedo incluir dentro de mi query que estoy adaptando a rails esta parte del query original?:

```
  SELECT B.Codigo, C.NombreCorto, B.Descripcion, B.HI, B.latitude, B.longitude, C.Direccion, ISNULL((SELECT SUM(TOTAL) 
FROM Venta 
WHERE RutaId=B.RutaId AND DiaO=B.DiaO AND CodCliente=B.Codigo AND Cancelada='0' AND TOTAL>0),0) AS TOTAL
```

Comment: probaste con esto http://stackoverflow.com/a/26125662/2144445 ?

Comment: Pienso que deberias separar los queries y hacer la lógica con ruby es más a rails way .... porque estás tratando de reproducir un SQL, en este caso es más limpio pensar en orientado a objetos

Answer (score 2):

ActiveRecord te brinda algunos helares para usar el ORM y simplificar el proceso de realizar consultas sencillas, se recomienda para consultas complejas evitar el ORM y enviar la consulta, ya no siempre podrás asociarlas a un único modelo. por ejemplo

```
@query = "SELECT B.Codigo, C.NombreCorto, B.Descripcion, B.HI, B.latitude, B.longitude, C.Direccion, ISNULL((SELECT SUM(TOTAL) WHERE RutaId=B.RutaId AND DiaO=B.DiaO AND CodCliente=B.Codigo AND Cancelada='0' AND TOTAL>0),0) AS TOTAL FROM BitacoraTiempos B LEFT JOIN Clientes C ON C.IdCli=B.Codigo  WHERE B.RutaId='161' AND B.DiaO='893'  ORDER by B.HI "

results = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(@query)
results.each do |row|
  puts row[0] # Codigo 
  ...
end
```

Comment: Gracias excelente pero tengo una duda, cuando haces el result.each do |row| eso supongo es en la vista? porque veo que result es una variable local